# Repeated computations in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Following is the code:
Code behavior is to generate power set of numbers from `0` to `n`.

`C` - represents the RDD which consists of all sets of size `l`

Where in iteration `l` all possible supersets of size `l + 1` are enumerated for the sets in `C` and stored back in `C`.

Some sets are eliminated from enumeration based on criteria which in this example is demonstrated via the condition on the output of random generator.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

from bitarray import bitarray
import random

def setadd(u, i):
    r = u.copy()
    r[i] = 1
    return r

def stringToBit(u):
    r = bitarray()
    r.frombytes(u)
    return r

def mapFunc(it):
    global bdTH
    global bdN

    for s in it:
        s = stringToBit(s[0])
        print(s)
        r = random.randint(1, 10)
        # elimination criteria
        if r  < bdTH.value:
            continue

        xmax = n - 1
        while not s[xmax]:
            xmax -= 1

        for x in xrange(xmax + 1, bdN.value):
            if s[x]:
                continue
            ns = setadd(s, x)
            yield (ns.tobytes(), 0)

def main(sc, n):
    phi = bitarray('0') * n
    C = [(setadd(phi, x).tobytes(), 0) for x in xrange(n)]
    print(C)
    C = sc.parallelize(C)

    global bdN
    bdN = sc.broadcast(n)

    global bdTH
    bdTH = sc.broadcast(random.randint(1, 10))

    l = 1
    while l <= n: 
        C = C.partitionBy(100)\
            .mapPartitions(mapFunc)

        l += 1

        if C.count():
            print('count: ' + str(C.count()))
        else:
            print('count: 0' )

        bdTH = sc.broadcast(random.randint(1, 10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf = conf.setAppName("test")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    n = 5
    main(sc, n)
    sc.stop()
```

Issues:
1. As the code is indeed to guarantee not evaluate any subset twice. However, the output does indicate that certain sets are evaluated twice.
2. Does the `broadcast` of the variable `bdTH` is guaranteed to be sent only after the `C` has been generated for iteration `l` or Spark can perform some optimizations.

[image: Issue1]

Answer (score 0):

Spark RDDs are lazy and, unless are cached and / or checkpointed, their complete lineage will be evaluated each time RDD is accessed.

Because you don't cache and `C` depends on previous `Cs` Spark will evaluate `C_i` once:

- For `C_i.count()`
- For `C_i+1.count()`

Because you `partition` Spark can reuse shuffle files, otherwise it would go back recursively all the way to the first RDD.

Comment: Can you clear up your language in the bulleted list?